# Animated, permanent dropdown from navigation like example. How to accomplish?

Tags: css

I really like the result of clicking the plus button at the end of the navigation on this page. http://demo.dinevthemes.com/planum/

I wanted to incorporate something similar into a site, but can't get it to work. From what I can tell, this is the code they're using, but when I test it out, the item stays visible and doesn't hide.

Any tips on why I am doing it wrong?
You can see the site I am incorporating it to here - http://dismantledesign.com/testsite/

```css
.toggle-top::before {
content: none;
display: inline-block;
font-family: "FontAwesome";
font-size: 18px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.toggle-top:before {
content: '\f067';
}

.menu-toggle::before, .toggle-top::before {
color: #1CCCA0;
}

.toggle-top {
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: 72px;
top: 44px;
}

.toggle-top.top-display:before {
padding-left: 5px;
padding-top: 0;
content: '\f068';
}

.top-left {
width: 35%;
}

.top-left,.top-right {
float: left;
}

.top-right {
text-align: right;
width: 65%;
padding-right: 40px;
padding-top: 15px;
}

.top-wrapper {
display: none;
background: #DEDEDE;
padding: 24px 72px;
}

.top-wrapper form {
margin: 0;
}

.top-wrapper ul.menu li {
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.top-wrapper ul.menu,.navigation-main ul {
padding-left: 0;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="toggle-top top-display"></a>
<div class="top-wrapper clearfix" style="display: block;">
<div class="top-left">
  <form method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform"     action="http://demo.dinevthemes.com/planum/" role="search">
 <label for="s" class="screen-reader-text">Search</label>
 <input type="search" class="field" name="s" value="" id="s" placeholder="Search">
 <input type="submit" class="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
</form>
</div>
<div class="top-right">
<div class="menu-topic-container"><ul id="menu-topic" class="top-menu"><li id="menu-item-3084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item- object-custom menu-item-3084"><a href="http://tel:+1915000000">+1 915 00-00-00</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2967" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2967"><a href="">current location</a></li>
</ul></div> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's nothing about animation or showing/hiding that menu area piece in the code you posted.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli That's why I came here, Evan. I am not finding that in the example's code either.

Answer (score 0):

The site you are referring to is using jQuery for toggleClass and the slideDown effect.  I created a small [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zaaz6Lka/1/) example that shows you how you can build it on your own.

Rather then adding a lot of animation with javascript, I implemented only one function for the toggle of classes `.active` for the `plus-icon` and `.open` for the `subnav`. The animation is done with css. In the beginning the `subnav` has `top: 0` and is not visible because it is below the `main-nav`. But when we toggle the class open it will move below the `main-nav` and is visible.

If you have any remaining questions, use the comment section.

```js
$(".subnav-toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(".subnav").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.subnav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .25s all;
}

.subnav.open {
  top: 58px;
}

.fa::before {
  content: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.nav--item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subnav-toggle.active {
  background: #ccc;
}

.subnav-toggle:before {
  content: '\f067';
}

.subnav-toggle.active:before {
  content: '\f068';
}

.nav--item.last {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav--item"><a href="#">Markup</a></li>
    <li class="nav--item"><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
    <li class="nav--item"><a href="#">Levels</a></li>
    <li class="nav--item"><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
    <li class="nav--item"><a href="#" class="fa subnav-toggle"></a></li>
  </ul>

  <div>
    <ul class="subnav">
    <li class="nav--item"><a href="#">Markup</a></li>
    <li class="nav--item"><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
    <li class="nav--item"><a href="#">Levels</a></li>
    <li class="nav--item"><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. I have been going through it and seeing how it all works, but I must be doing something wrong. The subnav is just chilling at the top of the page, overlapping the main nav. http://dismantledesign.com/testsite/#

Comment: the z-index of your header needs to be higher as the one of the .subnav, but the .subnav needs to be outside if the header. Else the subnav would have the same z-index.

Comment: It's hidden now, but the button doesn't bring it down.

Comment: You need to add the JavaScript snippet to toggle the state classes

Comment: I have the JavaScript snippet in the head of the html.

Comment: place the script right over the closing tag of the body-element